AWS lightsail not validating the TSL/SSL certificate for namecheap registered domain
I am trying to create TLS/SSL certificate for my domain in LightSail. I've already created the load balancers for my website. There are three domains (mysite.com, www.mysite.com, and media.mysite.com)
In my lightsail console, I did the Networking-> Selected my load balancer -> Custom Domains -> Create Certificate, and entered all the domains (mysite.com, www.mysite.com, and media.mysite.com). But it been stuck in the "Attempting to validate your certificate" status for the last 2 days.
I have clicked on the "Validation Details", and retrieved the CNAMES, and added these CNAMES to my namecheap CNAME section. But I'm seeing the same status since two days. Please see the picture below:

Is there anything else I should try doing?
